# Creating infinite zooming images

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, gif

What's an easy way to create a forever zooming & looping image like this: [image]

In particular what design applications (after effects comes to mind) allow recursive nesting of compositions?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I don't think it's a question of 'recursive nesting'. After all, it's only a loop; the last image links to the first one.

Comment: @Jongware you could achieve this effect by actively replicating the image... however if you could nest the original composition in itself (ie. recursion) then it would be super easy and wouldn't require complicated planning. I am just generally looking for tips on how to approach this problem.

Comment: I would think that particular image would have been created programmatically. It looks pretty recursive to me.

Comment: This one is actually easy, this is from a 3D animation and what is happening is a camera is passing through an array of replicated objects.  The distance for the animations loop is basically the frame right before the first key frame repeats, the effect is this.  Everything else moving and colors changing only matters that the timing match the framerate of what you are capturing - ie: 60 frames means I need my colors/animations/movement to loop at that rate as well. (Easily done via your animation tools in 3D animators.) You can also do this with just 25% of the image since its symmetrical.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a site that does not require any expertise.

http://gif-in-gif.com/

Create your animated perpetually zooming images in .gif format for free online!

Load 1 to 5 images, which will follow one by one periodic in animated gif. Each image can be up to 2 MB maximum and width/height can be up to 2000 px maximum. Acceptable formats: .gif, .jpg/jpeg, .png, .wbmp. Notice, that often using of just one image gives the best results.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use the answer body to say that you want to vote to close the question. You will get the privilege to review and cast close votes when your reputation reaches 250. Please be patient.